# Using OpenSceneGraph to detect two mice?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mouse, openscenegraph

There is osgGA::GUIEventAdapter in OpenSceneGraph that could detect mouse events. However, I want the program to detect two mice on the same computer and the program can only treat two mice as one. I know there is a Windows [MultiPoint Mouse SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/), but I think it is used in WPF with C#, not sure if it could be used in C++

Also, there is a [GlovePie](http://glovepie.org/glovepie.php), but it is not open source and not sure how to use that in vs2010.

[VRPN](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/vrpn/troubleshooting.html) may be a good choice, but do not know exactly how to implement two mice. Get the dll files of two mice and extract functions by vrpn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at "Raw Input" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543(v=vs.85).aspx)

From that page:

> An application can distinguish the source of the input even if it is from the same type of device. For example, two mouse devices.

Comment: So, you mean I have to use MFC and write VC++ interface and embed OpenGL into the GUI?

Comment: You don't need to use MFC - those are just win32 API calls. At application startup you need to call `RegisterRawInputDevices`, then respond to `WM_INPUT` messages in the message-handling loop. Sorry - I don't know about OSG or how this would fit into your application.

Comment: I encountered a problem: I have to use MainWndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT nMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) in order to get the WM_INPUT message?